# Javascript print / visualize all DOM elements as a Node tree keeping its structure

Tags: javascript, dom

after spending hours looking for the right answer, I decided to ask a question here.

I would like to visualize / print the entire Document Object Model (DOM) of a HTML document without 'flattening' its structure.

I found many solutions to loop through a DOM, but none of them keeps the structure.

An example is shown in the picture

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how to get the result done in Javascript?

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using DOM navigate to your HTML document by first taking the whole html document in a variable with:

```
var myDoc = document.documentElement;
vary body = myDoc.firstChild.nextElementSibling; //returns body
```

Assume `<h3>` is a first child of body then:

```
body.firstChild; 
body.firstChild.firstChild; //Text Node
```

Now to go next to `<P>`

```
body.firstChild.nextSibling; //would return <p>
```

Next you would easily traverse to its child like mentioned above.

I hope this might help!